# Unable to install Postgresql server on Centos 8, using Ansible

Tags: ansible, postgresql-12, dnf

I'm using Ansible to install Postgresql on my Centos 8 machine. This is the command that raises an error:

```
  - name: PostgreSQL | Install PostgreSQL | dnf
    dnf:
      name: "postgresql{{ postgresql_version_terse }}-server,postgresql{{ postgresql_version_terse }},postgresql{{ postgresql_version_terse }}-contrib"
      state: present
    environment: "{{ postgresql_env }}"
```

The error message looks like so:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false
failures:
- No package postgresql12-server available.
- No package postgresql12 available.
- No package postgresql12-contrib available.
msg: Failed to install some of the specified packages
rc: 1
results: []
```

I checked installed repositories with a command `yum -v repolist` and see this:

```
Repo-id      : postgresql
Repo-name    : postgresql yum repo
Repo-revision: 1589461611
Repo-updated : Thu 14 May 2020 04:06:52 PM MSK
Repo-pkgs    : 257
Repo-size    : 225 M
Repo-baseurl : https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64
Repo-expire  : 172,800 second(s) (last: Thu 01 Jan 1970 03:00:00 AM MSK)
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/postgresql.repo
```

For testing purposes I tried to install it by hand:

```
$ dnf install postgresql12
```

But it gives me this error message:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:19 ago on Fri 15 May 2020 01:41:17 PM MSK.
No match for argument: postgresql12
Error: Unable to find a match: postgresql12
```

Judging by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545635/install-postgresql-12-in-centos-8-got-no-match-for-argument-postgresql12) thread, the right command is this one:

```
$ dnf --repo postgresql install postgresql12
```

What is wrong with this and how it can be implemented with Ansible?

[image]

Comment: "Judging by this thread, the right command is..." Does the "right" command work when you run it from the command line? If it does, you may want to read about the `enablerepo` option of the `dnf` module.

Comment: @larsks. 1. Yes, the command works. 2. The repository is enabled - I checked it with `dnf repolist enabled` and see `postgresql` among other repos.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense: if the repository is enabled, then `--repo postgresql` should not be necessary.

Comment: @ larsks. If it does not make sense, let me attach a screen.

Comment: @larsks, attached a screen above.